# Boot stalls due to "Dependency failed for Hyper-V KVP Protokol Daemon."

Tags: 18.04, services

I'm using Proxmox and `ubuntu-18.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso`.
After every restart I get this:

```
A start Job is running for sys-devices-virtual-mis-vmbus\x21hv_kvp.devices
```

After 1m.30s, it prints

```
Dependency failed for Hyper-V KVP Protokol Daemon.
```

In Proxmox Forum someone said that I don't need this daemon, so I tried to remove it:

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove hv-kvp-daemon-init
```

or

```
sudo apt remove hyperv-daemons
```

but I get the error

```
Package not found
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 8):

Temporary solution: disable the service from starting:

```
systemctl disable hv-kvp-daemon.service
```

Relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1820063

Comment: Thank you for your help @Stephen, it works .)